# Date regEx allows input box to validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to figure out how to apply this regEx for a date that once the regEx matches the input value it then says the input is valid.

**HTML**

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="purchasedate" 
  id="purchasedDatePicker" 
  required="yes" 
  mask="99/99/9999"
>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('change blur keyup mouseup click', function() {
  var textDate   = $('#purchasedDatePicker');
  var dateString = $('#purchasedDatePicker').val();
  var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
    if (dateString == date_regex) {
      $('#purchasedDatePicker').valid();
    }
});

$("#purchasedDatePicker").datepicker({maxDate: new Date()});
```

Unfortunately mine is just allowing any thing through as long as the input is not empty. Any ideas or advise would be greatly appreciated!

Or maybe some help in how I can add/or create another rule for the jQuery Validate Plugin for it to validate.

```
    <script>
     $("#form").validate({
         focusInvalid: false,
    rules: {
        ownership: {
            required: true
        },
        vin: {
            required: true,
            validateVin: true
        },
        purchasedDatePicker: {
            required: true,
            validatePurchaseDate: true
        },

        // Same for other fields
    },
    messages: {
        ownership: "This field is required.",
        vin: "This field is required.",
        purchasedDatePicker: "This field is required.",
        // Repeat for other fields
    }
});

// create your custom rule
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateVin", function(vin) {
  var date = Number($("#vehicleyear").val());
  var re;
    if(date <= 0) {
        re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
    } else if (date >= 1981) {
        re = new RegExp("^[A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z\\d]{8}[\\dX][A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z\\d]{2}\\d{6}$");
    } else if (date < 1981) {
        re = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z\\d]{2,17}$");
    }
  return vin.match(re);
}, 'Please enter valid VIN.');


// create your custom rule
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validatePurchaseDate", function(purchasedDatePicker) {
  var date = ($("#purchasedDatePicker").val());
  var re;
    if (date) !== '') {
        re = new RegExp("/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/");
    }
  return purchasedDatePicker.match(re);
}, 'Please enter valid Purchase Date.');
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `dateString` when the validation runs? Also, attaching an event handler like that on `document` with no filter seems like overkill. Every mouse click *anywhere* in your document is going to cause this to run. And since you are using a date picker, doesn't it provide all this kind of validation for you? It seems like you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MattBurland . . . Datepicker does not include any inherent validation, other than capturing the date selected from the calendar.  A user can still type anything that they want into the text field that the Datepicker is bound to.

Comment: @DavidBrierton . . . Matt is right about the `$(document)`, though . . . you should put the event binding on the input itself.

Comment: @DavidBrierton - I added some more detail to my answer . . . this tested corrected locally, though, I'm sure that my testing setup was not the same as your full code.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the regex correctly.  You need to us its `.test()` method on the string that you are validating:

```
if (date_regex.test(dateString)) {
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's a more complete suggestion, including cleaning up the event binding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#purchasedDatePicker").on('change', function() {
        var dateString = $(this).val();
        var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
        if (date_regex.test(dateString)) {
            // do something for a valid value
        }
        else {
            // do something for an invalid value
        }
    });

    $("#purchasedDatePicker").datepicker({maxDate: new Date()});
});
```

**Note:** I added in the `$(document).ready(. . .` section in, just in case you hadn't included that in your code.  You have to include that so that the binding occurs after the page load.

Also, I assume your Datepicker has been configured elswhere to output the date in the `MM/YYYY` format (per your regex)?  Otherwise, you are always going to get invalid dates.

Comment: I think the problem is the jQuery validate plugin I cannot figure out how to add the rule in there so its just allowing it through with anything being entered. Do you have any experience with that plugin? Im new to JS and man does this get confusing with all these different types of plugins

Comment: I actually don't . . . I tend to use custom validation frameworks.  To test to see if the issue is in jQuery Validate or not, try simple using `alert()` or `console.log()` statements in the `if` check, to see if your code is behaving correctly.  If it is, then you can focus on looking into Validate, to see if you are missing something.

Comment: also its strange when I run yours and check the console log its not going through the if its hitting the else statement instead

Comment: Use [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) for this.

Comment: What value are you using to test?

Comment: @Sparky - I've removed the reference to `.valid()`, since I'm focusing on why his validation isn't working, and not how the validation result is being handled.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the valid() with me I thought that was saying it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
if (dateString == date_regex) {
    $('#purchasedDatePicker').valid();
}
```

You have the purpose of `.valid()` totally backwards.

You cannot "set" the field as valid by calling `.valid()`.

You are only supposed to call `.valid()` to run a validation test.

`.valid()` triggers a test of the attached field, evaluating the rules you've declared with the jQuery Validate plugin against the value of the field, and returns a boolean `true` or `false`.  It does not "set" or declare the field as anything.

[jqueryvalidation.org/valid/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

---

If you need to write your own separate validation function, you should use [the built-in `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) for this.  That way it's fully integrated into how the plugin operates.

Generic example...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("yourMethod", function(value, element, params) {
    // your function
    // -----------------------
    // 'value' represents the data in the field
    // 'element' represents the field itself
    // 'params' represents an array of optional parameters
    // -----------------------
    // return true to say it's valid
    // return false to say it's invalid and show message
}, "Please enter the correct value");

$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        myField: {
            required: true,
            yourMethod: true // <- declare the custom rule
        }
    }
});
```

---

Your new edited code...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validatePurchaseDate", function(purchasedDatePicker) {
  var date = ($("#purchasedDatePicker").val());
  var re;
    if (date) !== '') {
        re = new RegExp("/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/");
    }
  return purchasedDatePicker.match(re);
}, 'Please enter valid Purchase Date.');
```

There is no need to change the `value` argument into `purchasedDatePicker`... it still only represents the "value" of the field.  No matter what you call it, it represents what the developer has defined it to represent.

Also, `$("#purchasedDatePicker").val()` is already represented by the `value` argument... that's the point of `value`.

Then when you use the `value` argument, you can then apply the rule to *any* field, whereas your function restricts the rule to one specific field alone.

It should look more like this...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validatePurchaseDate", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/);
}, 'Please enter valid Purchase Date.');
```

or this...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validatePurchaseDate", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(value);
}, 'Please enter valid Purchase Date.');
```

I used the standard `this.optional(element)` with an "or" because it makes the custom rule "optional" for cases where you may not being using the `required` rule.  In other words, leaving out `this.optional(element) ||` would mandate the field as `required` even when you don't set the `required` rule to `true`.

[Browsing through the source code of the the plugin's `additional-methods.js` file should give you lots of ideas about how you can use use regular expressions to construct custom methods](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js).

Comment: hey sparky I did try using the add method do you see where I might be going wrong on my example above?

Comment: @DavidBrierton, your function arguments don't make sense.  Just leave `value`, `element` inside there and use those if you need them.  `function(value, element) { ...`

Comment: I wish I could up vote this like 100x you helped me understand many things I was unsure about!

Comment: I will does the top part go by name or by id? For some reason Im still not getting it to work properly I added yours to the bottom of mine can you not have more than one added rule or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71705/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-sparky).

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to change

```
if (dateString == date_regex) {
  $('#purchasedDatePicker').valid();
}
```

to:

```
if (date_regex.test(dateString)) {
    $('#purchasedDatePicker').valid();
} else {
    //do something when invalid
}
```